# When can a "first conditional" be mixed with the "second"?

Tags: conditionals, will-would, protasis

From my own research, I have seen people say that the first conditional cannot be mixed with the second, or the zero with the second. I have some example sentences, however, which I took from an essay about the pros and cons of having a small family. This was written by a native English speaker:

1. If a parent **wants** their children to have a university education, tuition fees **would** have to be paid for each child in order to be fair.
2. If a person **has** a larger family, by contrast, then more members **would** be able to work and generate more money.

Are these sentences grammatically correct? What is the meaning of using the present tense in the first clause, and *would* in the second?

Comment: Native speakers of English rarely refer to numbered conditionals. Although conditionals are understood, categorizing them into a numbered system isn't normally done—and doing so actually causes some confusion. The use of *would* is not inherently incompatible with any tense.

Comment: The 0-3 conditional constructions are common patterns. not rules. The  combination of the present tense in the if-clause with _would_ in the main clause is discussed in the following question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403146/would-present-tense-in-conditional-clauses

Comment: Closely related, possible duplicate of: [First conditional with “would” instead of “will”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112582/first-conditional-with-would-instead-of-will) Also related but with an inexplicable low view count: [Conditional conundrum](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/451646/conditional-conundrum)

Comment: also related: [Using “would” with the present tense in conditional clauses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45811/conditionals-in-the-future)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your explanations and links. They completely answer my question. I guess I had been making the wrong kind of search queries before.